# Swipe Gesture Recognizer can't detect the direction?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

If i am using gesture recognizer like this

```
 UISwipeGestureRecognizer *noRightShiftForVolume = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleVolumeViewSwipe1:)];
   [self.circleProgressBar addGestureRecognizer:noRightShiftForVolume];
```

Because i have navigation controller on the ViewController so this doesnt disable the swipe on the view.
But when i declare like this it work fine but dont know the direction of the swipe.

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *noRightShiftForVolume = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleVolumeViewSwipe1:)];
    [self.circleProgressBar addGestureRecognizer:noRightShiftForVolume];
```

The implemenation of the function is like this:

```
- (void)handleVolumeViewSwipe1:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender
{

    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        [applicationControllerShared() enableSwipe:NO];
        NSLog(@"good karens");

        if(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft){
        CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
        [animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
        [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromRight];
        [animation setDuration:0.50];
        [animation setTimingFunction:
         [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
        [_circleProgressBar.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:kCATransition];
        NSLog(@"Swipe Left");
        }

        if(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight){
            NSLog(@"Swipe Right");
        }
    }

    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        [applicationControllerShared() enableSwipe:YES];
        NSLog(@"good karens 110");
    }
}
```

In the navigation controller
 BOOL    eliminateSwipe;
 eliminateSwipe function look like this:

```
-(void) enableSwipe: (BOOL) state
{
    eliminateSwipe = !state;
}
```

enable swipe function disables the navigation controller swipe and gives me power to implement the function handleVolumeViewSwipe1.
I have circle progress bar which i want to detect left and right swipe and perform function according. Any clue how can i done that.

I have tried to implement this SwipeGestureRecognizerDirection in ViewDidLoad and ViewDidAppear but not working for me because of swipe feature of navigation controller.

This is solved with the help of UIPanGestureRecognizer and swipe can be detected with the following code

```
  if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        [applicationControllerShared() enableSwipe:NO];
        CGPoint velocity = [sender velocityInView:_circleProgressBar];

        if(velocity.x < 0)
        {
          NSLOG(@"swipe left");
}else{
 NSLOG(@"swipe right");}
}
```

Comment: Have you set `noRightShiftForVolume.direction` property of gesture ?

Comment: Yes but doesnt help at all. Swipe take me to navigation controller

Comment: Ok so it will popout from that viewController right ?

Comment: Yes exactly right.

Comment: Do you realise `if(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft){` isn't comparing anything? And you will need a separate `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` for each direction.

Comment: Yes i know but dont know what to do. Because when i define UISwipeGestureRecognizer instead of UITapGesture it doesnt work all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my exprience you need to apply delegate of `UINavigationControllerDelegate` to stop popGesture.

**Step 1 : Confirm Protocol in .h file.** (Optional Step)

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UINavigationControllerDelegate>
```

**Step 2 : Set delegate in `viewDidLoad`.** (Optional Step)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
}
```

**Step 3 : And disable gesture in `viewWillDisApper` in previos VC.** (Required Step)

```
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;
```

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: Thank you very much CodeChanger but this one i have already applied and it is not working at all.

Comment: Where you applied this ? in Previous screen or same screen of gesture view ?

Comment: I have applied it before and i have tried now as well. Didnt work. I have to detect the swipe direction. UITapGesture is working fine but dont know why not UISwipeGestureDirection

Comment: No What I am asking is in which screen you have applied above code ?

Comment: I have applied in both navigation as well as the viewController where i need swipe gesture